# Creating an image randomly fails in IE only

Tags: jquery

When I create an image in jQuery, set i's attributs with .attr() and then wait for it to load with .load() before animating the script randomly stops in IE. It always fails before the .load().

Any help would be very much appreciated. Even a different way of doing things would be helpful.

Thanks.

```
       $('<img />')
       .attr({
     src: new_src,
     width: '820',
     height: '575',
     alt: '',
     'class': 'bg_image'
    })
       .load(function(){
     //append image to #main2
     $('#main2').append( $(this) );
     //animate backgrounds
     $("#main2").animate({left: $main_left + "px"}, 'slow');
     $("#main").animate({left: new_left + "px"}, 'slow', function() {
      if($rand){
       document.location = $href + '?i=' + $rand;
      } else {
       document.location = $href;
      }
     });
       });
```

Comment: I don't get an error, the script just stops running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are **two thing** you need to do:

- **set** the `src` **after** the `onload` handler to ensure that the `event` is not fired before you could attach the handler
- **set** a handler to `error` event for **the link might be broken** and you have to handle that

**Code**

```
$('<img />').attr({
    width: '820',
    height: '575',
    alt: '',
    'class': 'bg_image'
}).load(function () {
    //append image to #main2
    $('#main2').append(this);
    //animate backgrounds
    $("#main2").animate({
        left: $main_left + "px"
    }, 'slow');
    $("#main").animate({
        left: new_left + "px"
    }, 'slow', function () {
        document.location  = $href;
        document.location += $rand ? '?i=' + $rand : '';
    });
}).error(function(){
       // simply redirect on error
       document.location  = $href;
       document.location += $rand ? '?i=' + $rand : ''  
}).attr("src", new_src);​ // set the src last
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some slight adjustment, like this:

```
$('<img />').attr({
  src: new_src,
  width: '820',
  height: '575',
  alt: '',
  'class': 'bg_image'
}).one('load', function(){
  //append image to #main2
  $('#main2').append(this);
  //animate backgrounds
  $("#main2").animate({left: $main_left + "px"}, 'slow');
  $("#main").animate({left: new_left + "px"}, 'slow', function() {
      document.location = $rand ? $href + '?i=' + $rand : $href;
  });
}).each(function() {
  if(this.complete) $(this).load();
});
```

The key here is that the `load` event doesn't fire in some browsers if it was loaded from cache, because the `load` happened when the `src` was set, instantly, *before* you bound the `.load()` handler.

To handle this, we're using [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to ensure the `load` handler only runs once, then after creating the images, we're looping through and if they're `.complete` (loaded from cache immediately most likely) we're calling [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) to make sure that event handler runs.